# How to configure Bitnami Redmine with the existing apache and mysql in my server?

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu-16.04, redmine, bitnami

I am having a Digital Ocean Droplet of Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache and mysql server configured for my wordpress sites . So now i am currently trying to install Bitnami Redmine into my server . While istalling the bitnami redmine , the stack again install apache and mysql server . So Is there any way to use the existing apache and mysql server for the Bitnami redmine .

Please let me know if there is any step by step documentation to proceed the further . Since i am newbie for ubuntu and redmine

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of using the Bitnami Redmine Stack is that you don't have to worry about configuring any other service/component that Redmine requires such as Apache, MySQL, Ruby, Git, Subversion, etc.

Therefore I recommend you to use the servers included in the Stack since they are up-to-date and already configured.

Redmine is configured to use Phusion Passenger on the Bitnami Stack. If you want to imitate the configuration that Bitnami uses to use your own Apache Server, you need to configure it to use Passenger. 
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/ruby/

Regarding the Database Configuration. You need to edit the file `/installdir/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/database.yml`.

> Please note that you have to change "installdir" with the path to the directory where you installed the Redmine Stack.